# Quadrature adjustment circuit

Tags: control-system

Consider following system:

[image]

To keep the mixer's LO and RF phases in quadrature I'm using a voltage controlled phase shifter. I know its phase change per volt constant in rad/V at my center frequency.

Now I need to design a feedback circuit to automatically adjust this phase shifter input but I'm unable to model the phase shifter in phase domain. 
This looks like a PLL but phase shifter is not a VCO so integrator VCO model is not correct.

How can I model the phase shifter in linearized phase domain? 
Or is this the right way to design this circuit? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'I'm unable to model the phase shifter ... '

When you wrote 'I know its phase change constant in rad/V  ...', you **have** modelled the phase shifter. I would expect any phase shifter to be fast enough that you can represent it as a simple gain, at the speed of any control loop you want to put round it.

All you need to do is to detect the average DC coming out of the mixer. This is the parameter that you need to drive to approximately zero to make the measurement. To do this, you need a high(ish) gain op-amp back from the mixer to the phase shifter.

If you put an integrator pole into the op-amp feedback, then it will control the mixer output to exactly zero (within the amplifier's input offset voltage).

As a control loop to stabilise, it's actually easier than a PLL (90 degrees easier to be exact) as it doesn't have that nasty VCO frequency to phase integrator 90 phase shift that PLLs have.